# Where is Ext Calendar Package for 5.1.1

Tags: extjs, calendar

I'm trying to develop a sample app with **Ext Calendar** but Calendar feature is pretty confusion! I have official/purchased **ext-5.1.1** and there are example calendar works but I can not find the package itself or I couldn't figure out how to use/implement it.

Is there **Calendar** feature for this release? And if then where it is or how I can use it?
 There are two `package/` folders;

- First one's path: `ext-5.1.1/packages`
- Second one: `ext-5.1.1/build/packages`

Also I've noticed there are not any official documentation on [Sencha Docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.1/index.html) for 5.1.1 release! So what's the trick here?

---

I've already tried using it with a View panel but it says:

```
GET http://nuri/CalTable/Ext/calendar/panel/Panel.js?_dc=1502807144839 404 (Not Found)
```

Here is the sample View:

```
Ext.define('CalTable.view.HOCalendar', {
    extend: 'Ext.calendar.panel.Panel',
    xtype: 'hocalendar',

    title: 'HO Calendar',
    itemId: 'hocalendar',
    width: 700,
    height: 700
});
```

**UPDATE**:
Screenshots for Calendar page and folder;

[image: page sample]
[image: folder sample]

Comment: I think the calendar component was introduced in 6.2 (premium), http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/guides/whats_new/whats_new.html

Comment: Can you point to the Calendar example with Ext5 you are referring to? The Calendar component was only introduced with ExtJS 6.2 as djmm182 already pointed out, but that of course wouldn't keep you or the sencha people from building a calendar from older/standard features like the grid.

Comment: @Mastacheata all I can point is those two screenshots which I've added just now. As I told, I saw this example so thought there would be some adjustment so make it usable.

Comment: found a link here http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.1/examples/calendar/index.html

Comment: The calendar sample was available in 4.2.x already: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.4/extjs-build/examples/calendar/index.html, however, all the calendar functionality is in the sample's code, not in the framework code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ExtJS 4.x and 5.x, the calendar code is in the calendar sample itself, and is not part of the official framework. As with all Sencha code samples, I guess they are intended to be copied from, so take everything you can get and improve around it.

How I got to the code online:

I opened [the calendar sample](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.4/extjs-build/examples/calendar/index.html) in Chrome, opened browser console, typed "Ext.ComponentQuery.query("calendarpanel")[0].initComponent", pressed enter, and clicked on the returned code. The "sources" tab opened with the source of the initComponent function. From there it was a right click on the source tab and "Reveal in navigator" to get the source tree:

[image]

If you have the sample on your hard disk, it may be even easier.

Answer (score 0):

Move the calendar package from:

```
{premiumLocation}/ext/packages/calendar
```

or

```
{yourWorkspace}/ext/packages/calendar
```